# Checkbox array not sending values

Tags: php, html

I have been stuck on something simple and I just can't find what is the problem. Sometimes it's good to have a outside look on it.

So I have this 4 checkboxes.

```
 <input id="inp_fjob"  <?=(isset($job) && $job=="catA") ? 'checked' : '' ?> onclick="disCheck('inp_fjob','inp_ojob','inp_ajob','');" required="" type="checkbox" name="only_job[]" data-parsley-maxcheck="1" value="catA" />
 <input id="inp_ojob" <?=(isset($job) && $job=="catB") ? 'checked' : '' ?> onclick="disCheck('inp_ojob','inp_fjob','inp_ajob','');" type="checkbox" name="only_job[]" value="catB">
 <input id="inp_ajob" <?=(isset($job) && $job=="catC") ? 'checked' : '' ?>  onclick="disCheck('inp_ajob','inp_ojob','inp_fjob','');" type="checkbox" name="only_job[]" value="catC" >
 <input id="inp_ljob" <?=(isset($job) && $job=="catD") ? 'checked' : '' ?>   type="checkbox" name="only_job[]" value="catD" />
```

In the PHP I do this check but it always end up in the *else* state.

```
$chArray = isset($_POST['only_job']) ? $_POST['only_job'] : array();

foreach ($chArray as $cBox){
    if ($cBox == "catA"){
        $job = "This is my first job since last 6 April and I have not been receiving taxable Jobseeker's Allowance of taxable Incapacity Benefit or a state of occupational pension.";
        $nicategory = "A";
    }
    if ($cBox == "catB"){
        $job = "This is now my only job, but since last 6 April I have had another job, or have receved taxable Jobseeker's Allowance or Incapacity Benefit. I do not receive a state or occupational pension.";
        $nicategory = "B";
    }
    if ($cBox == "catC"){
        $job = "I have another job or receive a state or occupational pension.";
        $nicategory = "C";
    }
    if ($cBox == "catD"){
        $job = "If you left a course of Higher Education before last 6 April and received your first Student Loan instalment on or after 1 September 1998 and you have not fully repaid your student loan, tick this:";
        $nicategory = "D";
    } else {
        $job = "nope.";
        $nicategory = "nope.";
    }
}
```

When I fill out the form and submit it, I print the $_POST and get:

> [only_job] => Array ( [0] => catB ) - which is is the correct checked checkbox. Respectively, catA when the first one is checked and etc.

I have been staring at it but just cant find the answer.
Suggestions?

Comment: Is this always output "catB" or else?

Comment: @d.coder Hi. No - actually it outputs the right checked checkbox.

Comment: I am bit confused here. You are saying it outputs right checked checkbox. But in you post you have mentioned it always end up in the `else` state??

Comment: hi, if you checked only one checkbox then you will get single value in array, if you want multiple checkbox of array then you have to checked on multible check box.

Comment: @d.coder Exactly! In the PHP I perform the check, I set the value and insert it in the database. However, its always the else state - "nope.".

Comment: @RaviShankar Hi. I need exactly one checkbox checked actually. I do not understand your input tho. Do you mean that I should not check the array?

Comment: Are you afraid of using radios?

Comment: `else if` - you are only evaluating against the last if above (so it will go into else as it is not catD). So you match catB and enter that if, but then you don't match catD so you enter the else for that statement too.  Also, you should never hit that else unless you have other inputs with the same name and not the four values in your ifs (when you change it to else if)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conditions are not proper. Either you should turn all `if` and `else` block into `if-elseif-else` block or you should use `switch` case like this:

```
$chArray = isset($_POST['only_job']) ? $_POST['only_job'] : array();

foreach ($chArray as $cBox){
    if ($cBox == "catA"){
        $job = "This is my first job since last 6 April and I have not been receiving taxable Jobseeker's Allowance of taxable Incapacity Benefit or a state of occupational pension.";
        $nicategory = "A";
    } elseif ($cBox == "catB"){
        $job = "This is now my only job, but since last 6 April I have had another job, or have receved taxable Jobseeker's Allowance or Incapacity Benefit. I do not receive a state or occupational pension.";
        $nicategory = "B";
    } elseif ($cBox == "catC"){
        $job = "I have another job or receive a state or occupational pension.";
        $nicategory = "C";
    } elseif ($cBox == "catD"){
        $job = "If you left a course of Higher Education before last 6 April and received your first Student Loan instalment on or after 1 September 1998 and you have not fully repaid your student loan, tick this:";
        $nicategory = "D";
    } else {
        $job = "nope.";
        $nicategory = "nope.";
    }
}
```

OR

```
foreach ($chArray as $cBox){
    switch($cBox){
        case "catA": 
            $job = "This is my first job since last 6 April and I have not been receiving taxable Jobseeker's Allowance of taxable Incapacity Benefit or a state of occupational pension.";
            $nicategory = "A";
            break;
        case "catB":
            $job = "This is now my only job, but since last 6 April I have had another job, or have receved taxable Jobseeker's Allowance or Incapacity Benefit. I do not receive a state or occupational pension.";
            $nicategory = "B";
            break;
        case "catC":
            $job = "I have another job or receive a state or occupational pension.";
            $nicategory = "C";
            break;
        case "catD":
            $job = "If you left a course of Higher Education before last 6 April and received your first Student Loan instalment on or after 1 September 1998 and you have not fully repaid your student loan, tick this:";
            $nicategory = "D";
            break;
        default:
            $job = "nope.";
            $nicategory = "nope.";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the problem! you end up with the last else, becasue all of the conditions will be checked

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the input. Actually I had it with the IFELSE before, but I changed it when I was trying to fix it. When I do it like this I face another problem. The PHP does not INSERT into the database nothing at all, which leads me to the thought that the value for $job and $nicategory is not set at all.

Comment: If your code still not working or unable to insert into database then please provide your latest code in [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)

Comment: I was avoiding the post the whole code because It is a bit long. What I find strange is that with the check that I did and value is set to "nope."  - the else statement - the INSERT is done. But when I change it - nothing is inserted and no error is displayed !?

Comment: There must be some sort of error that you will have to check. Without looking into the code i can't tell.

Comment: Have you tried printing final generated mysql query on browser and then execute it directly? Also, your code is not able to insert or update?

Comment: I am submitting the form so It does INSERT. I should've isolated the rest of the code. Apology. I will try with printing the query. Still, I find it strange, why it does insert with values "nope" before the edit with IFELSE and after I changed it to the IFELSE it does not insert at all.

Comment: @d.coder THE QUERY IS RIGHT! The $job and $nicategory values are right, but nothing is inserted? I dont know what is happening. You have been very useful thanks. I can't text you in private as SO says I do not have enough reputation. But I think I should delete this post now as it seems that this is not the problem. Any suggestions why it might be?

Comment: @d.coder Fixed it. The problem was in the $job string I am inserting. Here in Jobseeker's the 's breaks the query. No error or anything was displayed thought. Finally found it. Thanks for you input again.

Comment: Happy to hear that!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do a  **var_dump()** of the data you are getting in PHP so you can be sure you're getting the correct data in PHP.

It should return an array of values of the selected checkboxes.

If it's giving expected output, then the answer provided by d.coder should work.

And when you tried with if-else, had you used any javascript to uncheck all other boxes once one got selected ? Because if-else means you should be getting just one value.

Also, why aren't you using radio buttons for this ?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the input. Well, firstly I made it with checkboxes and I was not expecting a problem that big. Now  I will try with radiobuttons.